# How to make Powershell's Import-Csv correctly import blank spaces

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file where some of the cells have a blank space in them, and others are just empty. If I run

```
" " -eq ""
```

It returns False so Powershell itself understands the difference between a blank space and an empty string. But, I have a CSV file with the following content:

```
Header0,Header1,Header2,Header3
FillerData, ,,FillerData
```

When I import this and compare it I get the following:

```
PS C:\> $MyCSV = Import-Csv -Path "C:\MyCSV.csv"
PS C:\> $MyCSV.Header1 -eq " "
False

PS C:\> $MyCSV.Header1 -eq ""
True

PS C:\> $MyCSV.Header2 -eq " "
False

PS C:\> $MyCSV.Header2 -eq ""
True
```

So, Import-Csv defaults to treating CSV entries with a blank space as equal to an empty string, when they're not equal. I really need to import the blank spaces for my use case. Is there any way to make Import-Csv correctly import the blank spaces instead of treating them as empty strings?

Comment: Can you include some lines (including headers) of your csv as plain text here?

Comment: I added an example with some filler data to show the difference between a blank space and an empty string.

Comment: If you control the generation process for the csv, wrap meaningful spaces in quotes - see the output from ConvertTo-Csv for example: ```(new-object pscustomobject -property ([ordered] @{"Header0"="FillerData";"Header1"=" ";"Header2"=$null;"Header3"="FillerData"})) | convertto-csv``` gives ```"Header0","Header1","Header2","Header3"
"FillerData"," ",,"FillerData"``` - note the ```" "``` for Header1's value.

Comment: Of course, I think >95% of my questions have an accepted answer. However, I first need to verify that it actually works. Right now, trying this I get an issue that adding quotation marks makes Import-Csv import them literally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were a bit better at `regex` this could be improved but here is working solution, so basically `Import-Csv` will remove empty spaces by default unless you specify you need a literal blank space. A way to do this is to add opening and closing `"` on each cell but since your CSV doesn't have that, one way to add those `"` is this:

```
$csv = Get-Content ./test.csv

$newCsv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '(^|$)','$0"' -replace ',','","'
} | ConvertFrom-Csv

# As you can see, this results in 1 instead of 0
PS /> $newCsv.Header1.Length
1
```

#### Edit:

Actually, the `foreach-object` shouldn't be needed. This works fine too:

```
$newCsv = $csv -replace '(^|$|[\r\n])','$0"' -replace ',','","' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

#### Edit 2:

Adding [mklement0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479501/how-to-make-powershells-import-csv-correctly-import-blank-spaces/67479803#comment119272084_67479803) examples from his comments below.

- With `ForEach-Object` for lower memory consumption however less efficient:

> **`[^,]+`** matches any nonempty run of characters other than `,` *i.e. any nonempty field.*

```
$newCsv = $csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '[^,]+', '"$&"'
} | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

- Without `ForEach-Object` (most efficient solution):

```
$csv = (Get-Content -Raw ./test.csv) -replace  '[^,\r\n]+', '"$&"' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: Ah, so encircling the CSV content with quotation marks would solve that, interesting. I'll have a fiddle with both the CSV files and regex to see where this leads me. I'm doing a lot of importing with CSV files in loops so it might be better for me to just use your example and write the quotation marks to file before I use it in the script. I'll get back to you on this!

Comment: Great approach; you can simplify to a single `-replace` operation as follows: `-replace '[^,]+', '"$&"'`, but note that - as with your approach - this relies on fields having no _embedded_ `,` chars. (which would require such fields to be double-quoted already, which appears not to be the case here).

Comment: @mklement0 oh my, that's incredible, can you please explain how this works? `-replace '[^,]+', '"$&"'` i'm really really interested. never seen `$&` being used before.

Comment: `$&` is just an alias of `$0` - you can use them interchangeably. `[^,]+` simply matches any nonempty run of characters other than `,`, i.e. any nonempty field. `ForEach-Object` is worth using with direct `Get-Content` input if the file is too large to fit into memory.as a whole; otherwise, the most efficient solution is: `(Get-Content -Raw ./test.csv) -replace  '[^,\r\n]+', '"$&"' | ConvertFrom-Csv`

Comment: You've come with the right explanation and the fundamentals of the approach, so I think it makes sense to improve your answer rather than my posting another. Feel free to use information from my previous comments to update your answer.

Comment: Okay, been trying to verify this and now have a clearer understanding of where it fails! All of these assume that the CSV file does not have quotation marks around any of the cells. I cannot control if the CSV file will have quotation marks or not, so if the CSV file already has quotation marks, each entry gets two literal double quotation marks added to the end, probably because the regex adds the quotation marks even if they're already there. I'm currently trying to add some checks to the -replace, will get back to you shortly.

Comment: One solution (found here: https://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file) would be to import all CSV files, then export them back with Export-Csv as Powershell seems to always correctly add quotation marks to all cells, but having to do Import, export back, then re-importing just to ensure double quotation marks seems super-hacky.

Comment: @TanakaSaito I mean, you can always add a condition to your script checking if `'","'` is present then skip this method and use the normal `Import-Csv`

Comment: Oh my, of course! Thank you :) Yes, with those two solutions this works! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) @TanakaSaito